# Getting error while creating bmi calculator

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, double

Im creating a bmi caculator and im using the height and weight formula. I keep getting an erorr that says nan obese at the very end and i dont know what i'm missing or what i need to edit. Any help would be appreciated.

Output error:

```
Enter Weight in pounds: 150
Enter height (ft.): 
6
Enter height (in.): 
7
Your BMI is: NaN
Obese
```

BMI formula:
`BMI = (703 * weightInPounds) / heightInInches^2`

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bmi_Calc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method st
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //double weight;
        double weightInPounds;
        int feet; 
        int inches; 
        //int weightInPounds;
        int heightInInches;
        double height;


        System.out.print("Enter Weight in pounds: ");
        double weight = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter height (ft.): ");
        feet = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter height (in.): ");
        inches = input.nextInt();

        weightInPounds = 0;
        heightInInches = 0;

        double bmi = (703 * weightInPounds) / Math.pow(heightInInches, 2.0);
        double heightMeters = ((feet * 12) + inches) * .0254;

        System.out.println("Your BMI is: " + bmi);

        if (bmi < 18.5) {
            System.out.println("Underweight.");
        }

        if ((bmi >= 18.5) && (bmi < 24.9)) {
            System.out.println("Normal weight");
        }

        if ((bmi >= 25) && (bmi < 29.9)) {
            System.out.println("Overwight");
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("Obese");
        }

        input.close();          
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your bmi calculation numbers. That will tell you why you are getting NAN.

Comment: That is not a direct answer, so probably better as a comment.

Comment: If you give them a direct answer, in the beginning, they will never learn.

Comment: True enough, what I was saying is that your answer is most likely better off as a comment.

Comment: I feel like it has something to do with double heightMeters? I've been trying to change it but everything i do gives an error with heightInInches above

Comment: @dragon40226 thank you for the help my doubleheightmeters didn't make sense and my height and weight initializations werent correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
weightInPounds = 0;
heightInInches = 0;

double bmi = (703 * weightInPounds) / Math.pow(heightInInches, 2.0);
```

In above `weightInPounds` and `heightInInches` are zero so `bmi = 0/0` which is causing `NaN`

Thanks

Comment: I can't remove them because they need to be initialized and by adding 1 instead of a zero it changes the values to 1 in the lines below making your bmi 703 automatically

Comment: @Homsey They need to be initialized with the correct values, the actual height and weight, not some arbitrary number, before doing the division.